# Rails s3 bucket SSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-4

My rails 4 app is using an Amazon s3 bucket to store images. The configuration is pretty default with my production.rb file looking like this

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```

When the page loads an image, it loads it like this:

```
http://s3.amazonaws.com/themoderntrunk/designs/photos/000/000/052/large_thumbnail/product12.jpeg?1389721666
```

I wish for it to load with the prefix https:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/themoderntrunk/designs/photos/000/000/052/large_thumbnail/product12.jpeg?1389721666
```

without the SSL, my app is getting the warning in the console

```
he page at 'https://www.themoderntrunk.com/assortments/4/designs/52-product-12' was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed insecure content from 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/themoderntrunk/designs/photos/000/000/049/grid/product9.jpg?1389721643': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
```

Granted, in my production.rb file I have `config.forse_ssl = true`. My app also has SSL certificate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add it in the model

```
class Designs < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :photo, :s3_protocol => :https
```

Ref: [Is it possible to configure Paperclip to produce HTTPS urls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897710/is-it-possible-to-configure-paperclip-to-produce-https-urls)