# Paperclip 5.1.0 - undefined method [] for nil after update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using paperclip to store images. After updating to 5.1.0 (released tonight) I get the following error:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

My code in the view is this:

```
<%= @company.pic1.url(:large)%>
```

A change in 5.1.0 is the switch to leave s3_protocol as an empty string, if not set in the app: [Is it possible to configure Paperclip to produce HTTPS urls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897710/is-it-possible-to-configure-paperclip-to-produce-https-urls)
Following the advice there, I tried setting that string in the model to "http", "https" and :https, but didnt solve the problem.

What could be wrong? This is my model:

```
has_attached_file :pic1, :styles => { :large => "1000x600", :mid => "400x160", :thumb => "120x80>" }, :default_url => "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/server.assets/images/missing/image_missing_:style.png", :storage => :s3, :s3_credentials => APP_CONFIG["s3"], :path => ":class/:attachment/:style/:id.:extension", :s3_region => "eu-central-1", :s3_protocol => "http"
```

Thank you for any ideas how to solve this.

Full stacktrace here:

```
 NoMethodError - undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass:
    delayed_paperclip (3.0.0) lib/delayed_paperclip/url_generator.rb:11:in `for' paperclip (5.1.0) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:146:in `url'
  app/views/public/_single_company_slide.html.erb:47:in `_app_views_public__single_company_slide_html_erb__1195386595_87856600'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:339:in `render_partial'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:310:in `block in render'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:309:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:21:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:32:in `render'
  app/views/public/_landing_slider.html.erb:18:in `block in _app_views_public__landing_slider_html_erb___1162164959_87953600'
  activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:132:in `method_missing'
  activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:99:in `method_missing'
  app/views/public/_landing_slider.html.erb:17:in `_app_views_public__landing_slider_html_erb___1162164959_87953600'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:339:in `render_partial'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:310:in `block in render'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:309:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:21:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:32:in `render'
  app/views/public/home.html.erb:38:in `block in _app_views_public_home_html_erb___728996521_86764780'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/helpers/cache_helper.rb:190:in `write_fragment_for'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/helpers/cache_helper.rb:179:in `fragment_for'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/helpers/cache_helper.rb:115:in `cache'
  app/views/public/home.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_public_home_html_erb___728996521_86764780'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:303:in `realtime'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
  remotipart (1.2.1) lib/remotipart/render_overrides.rb:14:in `render_with_remotipart'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in `call'
  meta_request (0.4.0) lib/meta_request/middlewares/app_request_handler.rb:13:in `call'
  meta_request (0.4.0) lib/meta_request/middlewares/meta_request_handler.rb:13:in `call'
  rack-attack (5.0.1) lib/rack/attack.rb:147:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/deflater.rb:35:in `call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  remotipart (1.2.1) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  rack-contrib (1.4.0) lib/rack/contrib/response_headers.rb:17:in `call'
  meta_request (0.4.0) lib/meta_request/middlewares/headers.rb:16:in `call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  thin (1.7.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.7.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.7.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
  thin (1.7.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine-1.2.0.1-x64 (mingw32) lib/eventmachine.rb:194:in `run'
  thin (1.7.0) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
  thin (1.7.0) lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:19:in `run'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you add the full stacktrace please?

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question and I'm posting here just in case anyone is maintaining a legacy project (and not switching to ActiveStorage). xfactorial solution did the trick for me. `bundle update delayed_paperclip` bumped the version up to 3.0.1.

My tests are passing now and the app is running ok.

Answer (score 2):

Try updating your `delayed_paperclip` gem to `3.0.1`