# Rails 5.2.1 Images on View not showing up using Paperclip with AWS even though it displays the correct URL in src

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

This might just be a simple, obvious fix, although I have read similar questions and attempted solutions, I can't seem to figure it out.

I have a Post model which contains an image. When I upload the image, it successfully uploads to AWS but the post does not display it when I view that post.

My S3 bucket policy has been set so everyone can view.

I have my AWS Paperclip settings in my `config/environments/production.rb` file as:

```
 [...]
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    s3_credentials: {
      bucket: Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :bucket_name), 
      access_key_id: Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id), 
      secret_access_key: Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws,
      :secret_access_key), 
      s3_region: Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :region),
      s3_storage_class: :reduced_redundancy
    }
  }
```

Here is my Post model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :dislikes, dependent: :destroy
    attr_accessor :uploaded_image_for_io_adapters, :file_name, :top_text, :bot_text


    has_attached_file :image, styles: {   
        square: "250x250#",
        large:  "500x550!"
    }, 
    :convert_options => {
      :medium => "-quality 100 -strip"
    }, 
    default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
  validates_attachment :image, presence: true
  validates_presence_of :poster
    validates_presence_of :description
    validates :user, presence: true
    validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

My `app/views/posts/show.html.erb`

```
<div class="container">
  <center><table border="0" style="max-width: 500px;">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><%= image_tag @post.image.url(:large) %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><h3 class="text-left"><%= @post.description %></h3></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
      <td>
    <p>Posted by: <%= @post.poster %></p>
    <p><small class="text-muted"><%= @post.created_at %></small></p>
      </td>
      <td><p class="text-right">
        <div class="voting" style="text-align:center;" id="voting-div">
            <%= render partial: 'posts/likes', locals: {post: @post}  %>
            <%= render partial: 'posts/dislikes', locals: {post: @post}  %>
            <%= render partial: 'posts/post_score', locals: {post: @post}  %>
        </div>
      </p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><p><a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"> Flag as inappropriate</a></p></td>
    </tr>
  </table></center>
  <%= link_to 'Back', url_for(:back) %>
</div>
```

Here is the interesting part. On the post page where the image is not displayed, when I `View Page source`, I see under image source:
`<td colspan="2"><img src="//bucketname-images.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/posts/images/000/000/016/large/_editedimage_.png?1545616391"/></td>` as in the screenshot[image: page source displaying image]

When I `Copy Link Location` and paste, the URL is `http://bucketname-images.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/posts/images/000/000/016/large/_editedimage_.png?1545616391`. This URL displays the uploaded image on every computer I try which makes me suspect that the problem is coming from my view. I appreciate any pointers

### EDIT

When I check the console I see the following error:

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a
>   resource at
>   http://bucketname-images.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/posts/images/000/000/016/square_editedimage_.png?1545616391
>   (“img-src”).

Comment: Do you see any errors in your browser console? Might be a http/https issue.

Comment: @NMPennypacker Damn you were right!. I see an error on the console: Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://bucketname-images.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/posts/images/000/000/016/square_editedimage_.png?1545616391 (“img-src”).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running your site in `https`, you'll need to make sure that your S3 links are also served via `https` in order to avoid the `Content Security Policy error`. This answer should get you where you need to be in order to configure your image links to serve over `https`. [Is it possible to configure Paperclip to produce HTTPS urls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897710/is-it-possible-to-configure-paperclip-to-produce-https-urls)

The short answer is to use the `s3_protocol` option:

`s3_protocol: :https`, or in your case `s3_protocol: :http`

https://www.rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/master/Paperclip/Storage/S3

Comment: This worked! I edited `config/initializers/content_security_policy.rb` and changed `img_src :self, :https, :data` to `img_src :self, :http, :data`. I totally missed that this whole time

Comment: @i_use_the_internet, just make sure that you use https in production.